# Keyword not supported: 'attachdbfilename'

Tags: c#, database, forms

I'm new to C# in web development. At the moment I'm stuck at sending data from forms to database.

What I want to do basicly is send 2 words in database table which has ID column, odakle column and dokle column. My code looks like this:

```
@{
    var odakle = "";
    var dokle = "";

    if (IsPost)
    {
        odakle = Request.Form["odakle"];
        dokle = Request.Form["dokle"];

        var db = Database.Open("RequestDB");
        var intoDB = "INSERT INTO Zahtjevi (odakle, dokle) VALUES(@odakle @dokle)";
        db.Execute(intoDB, odakle, dokle);
        Response.Redirect("~/Home/Zahtjev");
    }
}
```

[I get this error](http://prntscr.com/2ewg0g)

My `connectionString` is good, everything is in place. but still I got this error. Can someone tell me what is wrong OR give me some examples how it should be done?

Comment: What DB are you connection to? And could you please post your connection string anyway?

Comment: Could you add your connection string ?

Comment: Database name is "RequestDB" and here is connectionString: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="d:\Users\Dino\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TAXee\TAXee\App_Data\RequestDB.mdf";Integrated Security=True

Comment: The (in my opinion **severely flawed**) `AttachDbFileName=` approach is **only** available in SQL Server **Express** edition. If you're using any other edition, you **cannot** just simply attach a `.mdf` on the fly (and you really shouldn't, anyway - SQL Server is a **server-based** system - let the **server** handle all the messy details of files and such - just talk to it using a **logical** database name)

Answer (score 0):

From the error seems that you've put wrong **using statement** in the code

Error is for **SqlServerCE** which is compact edition

Can you try **to change this using statements to SqlServer** which is not compact edition

It would be good to put some more code or explanation, otherwise it's hard to guess what's wrong here.